# jQuery datepicker 1.12.4 closes article container when click next or prev month button

Tags: jquery, datepicker, containers

I'm using a jQuery datepicker v1.12.4 inside a tag article:

```
<article id="registro">
<h2 class="major">Registro</h2>
<form method="post" action="#">
<div class="field half first">
  <label for="fechanac">Date</label>
  <input type="text" id="datepickermm" />
</div>
</form>
</article>
```

The script section is as follows:

```
var today=new Date();
$( function() {
$( "#datepickermm" ).datepicker({
inline: true,
minDate:today,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
} );
```

The article opens with an href tag:

```
<a href="#registro">Registro</a>
```

When a date is selected, all works fine, but clicking next or prev month buttons on calendar causes the "article" container closes and only calendar control remain on the screen.

Comment: Solved: The datepicker is OK, but clicking on month nav buttons it's like clicking outside the container, so any code that trigger body click events must be reviewed. In this case: `$body.on('click', function(event) {
 if ($body.hasClass('is-article-visible'))
 $main._hide(true);
});`